# What does the return value of an Access/VBA expression mean?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a huge expression for a textbox in the `CONTROL SOURCE`. Sometimes it returns `0` and sometimes `-1`, what do these values mean?

Comment: How can you be programming in Access and not know anything at all about the way in which Access/Jet/VBA store Booleans?

Comment: Boolean values in MSAccess can be viewed as integers, where zero is false and anything else is true... as far as I know, the only reason true is converted to -1 is to be able to sort the data. Besides that, I completely agree with David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164500%28office.10%29.aspx

> The Boolean data type is a special case of an integer data type. The Boolean data type can contain True or False; internally, VBA stores the value of **True as -1**, and the value of **False  as 0**

Answer (score 1):

VBA uses 0 for False and -1 for True.  (But generally a non-Null, non-zero value will be evaluated as True.)   So it looks like your expression is returning a Boolean (True/False) value.

Comment: who marked this down? this is completely the right answer but gaby answered it  correctly first

Comment: That answer came in as I was ready to submit mine.  I submitted mine because I wanted you to realize a value doesn't have to be -1 to be evaluated as True.  I don't mind the down vote.